# How to get the colored terminal back

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I tried to experiment with my Ubuntu, but then I realized that my terminal is not colored any more. Does anybody know how to colorize my terminal again so that I can distinguish between a folder and an executeable file?

[image]

Comment: Could you type `more ~/.bashrc` and show me the output?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question ([edit]). You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Thank you all. I just find the problem. It was the .bashrc that missing like Caramello said. Also I already fixed it.  Again, thank you..

Comment: You're welcome. But as @dessert stated, try adding a bit more detail to your questions next time. It helps make it easier to find what the problem is. Have a good day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create bashrc file following link http://bashrcgenerator.com After that, you should change file `/home/USERNAME/.bashrc` or `~/.bashrc` with new bashrc file.

Comment: This online tool doesn't create the whole file, but only the PS1 line. To get a fresh `.bashrc` file for your exact system back, just copy it over from `skel` with: `cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

With the terminal open, right-click anywhere in the blank space where you may type (not the Title Bar where the close, minimize & maximize buttons are) and click **Profiles** > ***Profile Preferences***. From here you should navigate to the Colors tab and mess around with the settings to satisfy your taste; personally, I like the Linux console scheme with a slightly transparent Black background and Light Purple text, #swag

Comment: Thank you Ebeeze. I just find the problem. It was .bashrc that missing. Also I managed to fixed it : .)